How to return js function data in in google auth environment for use in another function
My test script is:
// Test file that aquires authorization to list file ids/names from My Drive > ocrTarget

const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;


const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
// File id of the file to download
const FILEID = '11Sejh6XG-2WzycpcC-MaEmDQJc78LCFg';


// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'DownloadFileToken.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\googleDriveDev\\credentials.json';

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fsp.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fsp.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fsp.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}


/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of pageSize number of files (using query to define folder of files)
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
 
 
  drive.files.list({
    corpora: 'user',  
    pageSize: 100,
    // files in a parent folder that have not been trashed 
    // get ID from Drive > Folder by looking at the URL after /folders/ 
    q: `'11Sejh6XG-2WzycpcC-MaEmDQJc78LCFg' in parents and trashed=false`,    
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
     
        var idFiles = [ ];
        files.forEach(function(file, i) {
        idFiles.push(file.id);
        idFiles.push(file.name);
        });

        // Store file id/name pairs for use later
        var fileIdentity = [];

        // Iterate over idFiles array with step of 2
        for (var i = 0; i < idFiles.length; i += 2) {
            // Push pair of values into d array
            fileIdentity.push([idFiles[i], idFiles[i + 1]]);
        }
        
        // Access pairs using indices in order to pass an array pair of file id/file name into a function
        for (var i = 0; i < fileIdentity.length; i++) {
            console.log("File id:", fileIdentity[i][0], "has file name:", fileIdentity[i][1])       
        }

    } 
    else 
        {
        console.log('No files found.');
        }

        
  });

}

authorize().then(listFiles).catch(console.error);

Output:
C:\googleDriveDev>node ./exportTest3.js
File id: 15lsfdIP1Jne-x-rPI57BtWQE3W4ciZzDz9Wy4uU9J98 has file name: 31832_226133__0002-00104
File id: 1RK_172AaDBLji941voUn1TeAg6u6We-UQ8G280e2xsg has file name: 31832_226133__0002-00105
File id: 13B0Kt6PhQYalqh046eXJxnbT9ZCLZDhv2XZqF5SHdV4 has file name: 31832_226133__0002-00106
File id: 1Aj_jQ3nSZAMPlap7fC6lk2uEN7ajIuUL5Kx-JusE1O4 has file name: 31832_226133__0002-00107
File id: 1rTnen5Zhb-aV9k82cNqbbVVl8f54QDGRAdT6o7Ob2b8 has file name: 31832_226133__0002-00108

------------------><---------------
Instead of outputting the id/names array pairs within function listFiles() I want to return the array fileIdentity and iterate over it outside the function.
I don't have much JavaScript experience. I find simple function returns in exercises okay. But this example has extra complications. Placing return fileIdentity has been okay (no errors) But when I try to output what's returned my array var is determined to be undefined and trying another combination I got:
The API returned an error: Error: The request is missing a valid API key.

Having this data outside of the function would be useful in passing it to the next function in the process.

you'll have to fix The request is missing a valid API key. first, then you'll want to use a callback to get the data out of that function

Just return a promise of the asynchronous file list per Tanaike's answer and the linked duplicate.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?
From:
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
 
 
  drive.files.list({
    corpora: 'user',  
    pageSize: 100,
    // files in a parent folder that have not been trashed 
    // get ID from Drive > Folder by looking at the URL after /folders/ 
    q: `'11Sejh6XG-2WzycpcC-MaEmDQJc78LCFg' in parents and trashed=false`,    
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
     
        var idFiles = [ ];
        files.forEach(function(file, i) {
        idFiles.push(file.id);
        idFiles.push(file.name);
        });

        // Store file id/name pairs for use later
        var fileIdentity = [];

        // Iterate over idFiles array with step of 2
        for (var i = 0; i < idFiles.length; i += 2) {
            // Push pair of values into d array
            fileIdentity.push([idFiles[i], idFiles[i + 1]]);
        }
        
        // Access pairs using indices in order to pass an array pair of file id/file name into a function
        for (var i = 0; i < fileIdentity.length; i++) {
            console.log("File id:", fileIdentity[i][0], "has file name:", fileIdentity[i][1])       
        }

    } 
    else 
        {
        console.log('No files found.');
        }

        
  });

}

authorize().then(listFiles).catch(console.error);

To:
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    drive.files.list(
      {
        corpora: "user",
        pageSize: 100,
        // files in a parent folder that have not been trashed
        // get ID from Drive > Folder by looking at the URL after /folders/
        q: `'11Sejh6XG-2WzycpcC-MaEmDQJc78LCFg' in parents and trashed=false`, 
        fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
      },
      (err, res) => {
        // console.log(err);
        if (err) {
          reject("The API returned an error: " + err);
          return;
        }
        const files = res.data.files;
        if (files.length) {
          var idFiles = [];
          files.forEach(function (file, i) {
            idFiles.push(file.id);
            idFiles.push(file.name);
          });

          // Store file id/name pairs for use later
          var fileIdentity = [];

          // Iterate over idFiles array with step of 2
          for (var i = 0; i < idFiles.length; i += 2) {
            // Push pair of values into d array
            fileIdentity.push([idFiles[i], idFiles[i + 1]]);
          }
          resolve({ fileIdentity, msg: "" });
        } else {
          resolve({ fileIdentity: [], msg: "No files found." });
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

authorize()
  .then(listFiles)
  .then(({ fileIdentity, msg }) => {
    if (fileIdentity.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < fileIdentity.length; i++) {
        console.log("File id:", fileIdentity[i][0], "has file name:", fileIdentity[i][1]);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  })
  .catch(console.error);


In this modification, I simply modified your showing script.
When fileIdentity has values, the values are shown with console.log("File id:", fileIdentity[i][0], "has file name:", fileIdentity[i][1]). When fileIdentity has no values, No files found. is shown with console.log(msg).
When an error related to the request to API occurs, the error is shown with catch(console.error).


Thank you for improving my code. This doesn't solve my problem but it helps.

@Dave Thank you for replying. About This doesn't solve my problem, I have to apoplogize for my poor skill. Can I ask you about the detailes of your current issue?

No apologies required ;-) I have achieved what I wanted. I got help. See https://gist.github.com/willdave865/724d434d40ca9cc126533fff847d7d4c The solution is at line 77. I don't understand all the code. But it works.
